# values not getting stored one by one in an array after each button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was trying to build a program and got a problem of storing data into an array after each click of a button. After each click, I am sending some data through ajax to a php page and i want to store all sent data in an array and display them in an tabular format later.

I have checked in the console by inspect element and the problem arising is its always overwrites the old value in an array to a new value. I dont find where i am wrong. if someone please help me will be of great help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#feed_btn").hide();
  $("#finish_btn").hide();

  $("#start_btn").click(function() {
    $("#start_btn").hide();
    $("#feed_btn").show();
  });
});

var i = 0;

function PerformGame() {
  i++;
  $.ajax({
    url: 'perform_game.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      'button_clicked': i
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.game-body {
  background-color: AED264;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="farm_game" method="POST">
  <button type="button" name="start_btn" id="start_btn">Start Game !</button>
  <button type="button" name="feed_btn" id="feed_btn" onclick="PerformGame();">Let's Feed Now</button>
  <button type="button" name="finish_btn" id="finish_btn">Finish Game !</button>
</form>
```

```
<?php
  $no_of_times_button_clicked = $_POST['button_clicked'];
  $animal_person_array = array(Farmer,Cow1,Cow2,Bunny1,Bunny2,Bunny3,Bunny4);
  $a = $animal_person_array[array_rand($animal_person_array,1)];

  $final_result_array[] = array($no_of_times_button_clicked => $a);

  echo json_encode($final_result_array);
?>
```

Comment: You need some sort of storage like db so when button is clicked you store the num of clicks on second click you increment the previous stored result

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile But I dont want to maintain a Db for the simple task. I think of something like array where i can store the values and later display it in an tabular format.

Comment: You'll neeed to at least initialise a session on the server-side.

Comment: Woud a better option for you not be to collect all of the data on each click on the client side then send it all at once?

Comment: If you want to avoid a DB you can either: remove php from the picture and just keep your variables in javascript; or post the entire array back to the server in addition to your current parameters.

Comment: If you don't want to use server side storage you could use a cookie, sessionStorage or localStorage. This would also remove the need for the AJAX request too

Comment: `array(Farmer,Cow1,Cow2,Bunny1,Bunny2,Bunny3,Bunny4)` those need to be quoted.

Comment: `$_POST['button_clicked']` where is the attribute for that? Enable error reporting.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner in the ajax setup data{`button_clicked` }

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile 10-4. Still [this...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53323029/values-not-getting-stored-one-by-one-in-an-array-after-each-button-click#comment93526985_53323029) that should be throwing errors via php.

Comment: Yes true @FunkFortyNiner should give error

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile You're the only one who seems to agree. Unless they only wrote that as pseudo code; that I don't know.

Comment: unless there's more code otherwise should give errors @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile No idea; I'll vote as unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not work, because each time you make the AJAX call you start a new instance of the PHP script, that does not know about the other calls.

You have a couple of options:

- Store the previous array entries in a server session
- Store the previous array entries in a DB
- Collect all data about buttons on client side (in Java Script) and send the whole array to your PHP script

For your case I would recommend a [server session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Here is an example code (untested) with rudimentary session handling:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if ($_POST['start_game'] !== null)
  {
      $_SESSION['final_result_array'] = [];
      die();
  }

  $final_result_array = isset($_SESSION['final_result_array'])
      ? $_SESSION['final_result_array']
      : [];

  $no_of_times_button_clicked = $_POST['button_clicked'];
  $animal_person_array = array("Farmer","Cow1","Cow2","Bunny1","Bunny2","Bunny3","Bunny4");
  $a = $animal_person_array[array_rand($animal_person_array,1)];

  $final_result_array[] = array($no_of_times_button_clicked => $a);

  echo json_encode($final_result_array);

  $_SESSION['final_result_array'] = $final_result_array;
?>
```

**Important:** You need to re-initialize your array at every start of a game or it will keep adding to it. For that just call the script with the parameter `start_game = true` when clicking on the `start_game` button.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. But am a newbee to this type of session management. Could you please elaborate more like how can i store those values in a session and then retrieve them at last ?

Comment: All you need to do is start a sever session and retrieve your array from the session at start and store your array into the session at the end. PHP will then make sure that information is kept persistent between calls to the script.

Comment: It's a bit much to expect someone to type out the code for you, he has told you what your options are, time to get googlin'

Comment: To be fair, even if you get the session going your code has other issues. Personally, I don't think php is necessarily the best way to do this, do you have to use php for this?

Comment: @Nunchy yes i have to use php for this ..as i am developing a small game, otherwise i dont have any idea about like how could i approach using javascript.

Comment: No problem, doing it in JS would probably simplify things a lot for you. You said you didn't want to mess with databases and it was just a simple app which is why I was wondering if you really needed php.

Comment: @Snehasis To monitor your PHP script you want to add some l logging to it. In its easiest form something like this: `file_put_contents("log.txt", var_export($_SESSION, true) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Hey Buddy, Thanks to your kind help. Yours untested piece of code is working fine for me and its made my day. Thanks again !